# A scheme in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I have 5 statements and some of them are equivalent, for some of them implications hold only in one direction. I would like to draw the scheme of these relations in LaTeX. Fortunately, two pairs of these statements are equivalent, so the scheme will not be overloaded with arrows.

In fact, there will be a triangle with 3 nodes (1),(2),(3) with some arrows between them, and (4) will have just a connection with (2), (5) will have the only connection with (3).

How to draw it in LaTeX? Here is an example from Visio: however I need arrows to be without corners and like `$\Rightarrow$` or `$\Leftrightarrow$`.

[image: The scheme]

Comment: I think a link to a graphical example would be useful here.

Comment: @Joseph: Could I upload it here, or I should use an external website? If I could do it here, please tell me how.

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again. (There is an 'Add image' button in the question editor.)

Comment: Do you need that rectangular arrangement of the arrows between 4 and 2, and 3 and 5, or should that just be a straight line without corners?

Comment: @Brent: without corners (I wrote "angles" instead (( ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the closest to $\Rightarrow$ I found. I was too lazy, so it's with absolute positioning ;)

EDIT: Should have read the question. Now with only one connection between 2/4 and 3/5

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle] (s1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[draw,circle] (s2) at (-1.6,-2) {2};
\node[draw,circle] (s3) at (1.6,-2) {3};
\node[draw,circle] (s4) at (-4,-3) {4};
\node[draw,circle] (s5) at (4,-3) {5};
\path
    (s2) edge[->, double distance=1pt, >=latex', bend left=40] (s1)
    (s3) edge[->, double distance=1pt, >=latex', bend right=40] (s1)
    (s3) edge[->, double distance=1pt, >=latex', bend left=60] (s2)
    (s2) edge[<->, double distance=1pt, >=latex'] (s4)
    (s3) edge[<->, double distance=1pt, >=latex'] (s5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Five strange statements.}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: surprisingly works now, strange that it does not work before.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but here's a possible answer using TikZ...

Edited: I'm not very experienced with figures; here's something "that appears to work", and incorporates @Nikolaus Mayer's (+1) arrows. Note that figures are *floats*, so your figure, rather than disappearing, may have just moved to a less convenient point in your document...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum width={3em},node distance=6em}]
\node (a) {1};
\node [below left of=a] (b) {2}; 
\node [below left of=b] (d) {4}; 
\node [below right of=a] (c) {3}; 
\node [below right of=c] (e) {5}; 
\draw [->] (b) -- (a);
\draw [->] (c) -- (a);
\draw [->] (c) -- (b);
\draw [<->] (b) -- (d);
\draw [<->] (c) -- (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's almost perfect. Is it possible to make arrows of the desired style like `$\Rightarrow$`?

Comment: also, how can I label this picture and write a capture for it? If I use `figure` environment, the picture vanishes.